# C3.js Customize X axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, c3.js

I am using C3.js.
I have a grid which contain few plots which is on the same value of the X axis. Can i make the plot place depends on the X axis value?

I tried to use the c3js axis library, but it doesn't help:

```
  axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'category',
             categories: ['1235', '2523', '2563', '1234']
        }
    }
```

The fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q8h39/95/
is what i have at the moment.

But the result should be below:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try multiple axes chart in c3.js, through this you can achieve what you are looking for as like given in below :-

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        xs: {
            'data1': 'x1', 
        },
        columns: [
            ['x1', 10, 30, 45, 50, 70, 100], 
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250], 
        ]
    }
});
```

JSfiddle for this:-http://jsfiddle.net/q8h39/96/

Comment: thanks sir this is wat i lookin for , am i able to use this on the Y axis as well?